# How to make a conductor "conduct"?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm new to CM, but it seems that the Conductor is an appropriate pattern to manage the screen workflow of an application. I haven't figured out how to make the conductor, well, "conduct" what screens are displayed beyond the initial screen.

I'm looking for a place to hook into CM's conductor that will detect when a screen is dismissed. Once a screen is dismissed I can call out to a state-machine like class that decides what Screen should be displayed next. This way each screen is unaware of the other screens in the application.

ie: Startup with a login screen, user logs in, conductor gets a "screen deactivated" notification and then asks a component what screen it should display next.

Comment: why can't you just call the "state-machine like class" from the action on the active screen that completes its applicable lifetime?

Comment: Each screen knows about its parent, they could tell the parent when they're deactivated.  Also checkout Show.cs in http://mediaowl.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your shellviewmodel inherits from a ConductorBase, the current view is bound to the ActiveItem property. To conduct, you must call ActivateItem and DeactivateItem existing methods on shell. This will trigger the magic of conducting views, deactivating and activating viewmodels.

Comment: You can override methods from Conductor viewmodel and then use your state machine class to determine which viewmodel will be the next to be activated. If your conductor inherits from Conductor.Collection.OneActive, there's a method to override the behavior of the next item to be activated.

Comment: Great answer, add to it that the best way to communicate between the moving parts in a C.M project is the Event Aggregator... The current view raises an event in the aggregator that it has been dismissed, then the Conductor receives the event (because it subscribed) and handles screen transition appropriately.